# Dead USB: Is there a way to recover data from it?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, file-recovery

I have this USB stick which seems to be dead.

dmesg -w command:

```
[ 6283.970828] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 6284.123086] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=1169, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 6284.123106] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 6284.126803] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6284.127677] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 6285.135658] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     XXXXXXXX U1169CONTROLLER  0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 6285.136342] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 6285.136616] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 6285.137425] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

lsblk command (Show only the entry needed)

```
sdc             8:32   1     0B  0 disk
```

And fdisk -l not shows the device.

Now the question: There is a way to recover the data?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Often it's possible but the question is, is it feasible as a DIY project?

If I read it correctly the physical capacity of the pendrive is 0 bytes, it is however detected. In general it means the controller works but it is unable to speak with the NAND.

Issue is then:

- NAND is issue
- or some issue  in path from controller > NAND

If you're like most people (?) you may simply lack the tools such as a multimeter, some type of magnification and a soldering iron.

These would also allow you to trouble shoot and fix common issues like broken connectors and blown diodes for example: In this example connector was ripped off and diode blown. A USB wire is attached at pads where connector normally sits and diode replaced by copper wire.

[image]

If you have hot air station you can even attempt swapping the NAND to a known good identical USB flash drive in case the controller is the issue.

Note that in general such soldering jobs are not good first projects.

But even if you have such tools, if the NAND itself is the issue, you'd still be stuck. This does not mean the data can not be recovered, however you'd need someone with the proper hardware to desolder and dump the NAND and the software to convert the dump to a logical image which you can then recover the data from using even an ordinary file recovery tool.

NAND chips removed:

[image]

Dumping NAND chips using a NAND reader:

[image]

Is it possible to recover data from a USB flash drive: Often, yes. By yourself: Some times and depending on skills and tools.

Just a FYI, here's a video from a guy that inspired me to go learn about this stuff: https://youtu.be/ZlXDeyDBUI8

Comment: Thank you for the reply, a very comprehensive explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

USB Sticks are not the most reliable devices.

You definitely should make backups of whatever is on the stick and generally do not use the stick for other that a short term (less than one day) backup to move data between computers.

Can you recover the data?  Generally for most users NO (> 95%)